# Using Mockito is necessary to overwrite all methods?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

Using it to test in Spring.
Using @Mock Mockito is necessary to overwrite all methods replies of the original class with when clauses? And what is the difference with @MockBean ?

Comment: Yes, you should overwrite all methods if any calling on mock object. Only return any value with when clauses. @Mock creates mock object and you have to set to related tested class. But MockBean is **If any existing single bean of the same type defined in the context will be replaced by the mock, if no existing bean is defined a new one will be added.**

Comment: Thanks. Then Mock does not create a new one. Cool. SpyBean does not create a new one neither. Right?

Comment: Yes, Mock creates but not bind autamaticly, it is up to you.Spy is the real object,so if you dont set to tested class, you can not use when clause . Spy is real object of mock in shortly. You dont have to write when clauses on this spy object. If you want to check , yes you can check. If not dont write any when clause.

Answer (score 0):

Its not accessory to override overwrite all methods.

@Mock is pure Mockito library where @MockBean is spring implementation of Mockito

So in your spring component class if not defined @Autowired fields (Just like simple java class to mock as object) then use @Mock annotation to mock the object of that class.

But your sping component class has @Autowired fields and you want spring container initialize that fields as Mock object then use @MockBean annotation (spring will do mock and autowire it).

For ex

```
class Test {

public void testMethod(){ -- some code --}

}
```

The you can use @Mock annotation for Test call to mock it. There is no other dependencies or fields in Test class.

```
@Component
class Test {

@Autowired 
Other other;

public void testMethod(){ -- some code --};

}
```

Then you can mock Other object using @MockBean if you want to mock it and pass by the functionality of other (i.e we mock DAO layer and not calling actual logic). Spring container will initialize that other field.